# strange NullPointerException inside Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, garbage-collection

In my Android app, I have found an error that happens in about 0.5% of attempts. This error is generate from an `NullPointerException` but this is strange.

Below is summarized the code the generates that exception:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();  
    mInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_INFO); // mInfo is a private member of Activity
    if(mInfo == null)
        finish();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fermata_details);

    first = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(IS_FIRST_LOAD, true); // also onSaveInstanceState is used for maintain that value across configuration changes.

    if(first){
        first = false;
        // a new fragment is inflated in the FrameLayout of the Activity
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        DetailsFragment fragment = new DetailsFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_fragment, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

The Activity also has the following public method:

```
public int getIdInfo(){
    return mInfo.getId(); // here occurs the NullPointerException.
}
```

The method `getIdInfo()` is called from the Fragment in this way:

```
(MyActivity)getActivity()).getIdInfo();
```

I think that is a strange behavious, since the `NullPointerException` tells that `mInfo` should be null. But the condition in the onCreate:

```
if(mInfo == null)
    finish();
```

should ensure that if the mInfo is null the Activity is finished.

Where can be the error? Can be related to Garbage Collector behaviour?

**NOTE:** I'm not able to get much more infomation about the error (the error was detected 3 times over 600 attempts), since I have retrieved this exception form `Google Analytics`, that gives my just this row:

```
NullPointerException (@MyActivity:getIdInfo:122) {main}
```

Comment: I don't see savedInstanceState.setBoolean(IS_FIRST_LOAD, first) anywhere ?

Comment: To avoid writing a lot of code in my question, I have omitted it. But as said in the comment I have use it inside the onSaveInstanceState() callback

Comment: When do you call (MyActivity)getActivity()).getIdInfo(); in Fragment ?

Comment: Since it requires to access that info. The Fragment uses that info for calling a ws. The ws is called inside a Task.

Comment: if `(MyActivity)getActivity()).getIdInfo();` crashes, then it is `getActivity` that is null. You call it in a place where the fragment may be detached.

Comment: But the exception is not generated at thet line but here: return mInfo.getId(); This means that the method getIdInfo() is accessible (using the activity) so the activity can't be null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are getting not-fully created Activity: one that has detected null and called finish(). Please consider the fact that `finish()` does not cause the `onCreate()` method to stop.

I suggest:

```
mInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_INFO);
if(mInfo == null) {
     finish();
     return;
}
```

One could suspect that FragmentManager will not try to attach any fragments to activity that called finish() on itself but I'm not able to find any documentation of that behavior.

Comment: I think you are right. Using a return can ensure that the successive code will not be executed?